# CSS Hover on Div Container; Display Image

Tags: html, css

I need an image to appear when the overall container is hovered.  I've tried accessing the class directly on the image and I've tried nesting the image in a div with no success.  I have a feeling it is regarding the selectors ~, >, etc. but I cannot track this down for the life of me.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="sigma">
      <img src="http://www.wrightslaw.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/assets/img/plugin-icon/icon_info.png" align="right" style="margin: 7px 0;"  />
    </div>      
  </div>
  <div id="chart1" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background-color: #eceded; 
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  width: 290px; 
  height: 30px;
}

.sigma {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover~.sigma{
    display: block;
}
```

I also have a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sthompson/eovn8o3p/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), `~`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eovn8o3p/3/)**

`.sigma` is a descendant (grandchild) of `.container` and `~` only applies to siblings. If for some reason you need to enforce the hierarchy, you could also use `.container:hover > div.info > .sigma`.

Comment: better answer w/ explanation and fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

`sigma` is not a sibling of the `container`, so the `~` combinator in your selector is not appropriate. Neither is it an immediate child, so you should use just a simple selector instead:

```
.container:hover .sigma {
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/eovn8o3p/4/)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith And fiddle! Just not bold :o)

Comment: oh lol yeah you are right! I up-voted you both anyways (that's what counts)

Comment: better answer w/ explanation and fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/eovn8o3p/5/

```
.container:hover .sigma{
    display: block;
}
```